# Confusing comments in MTK Droid Tools

Tags: motorola-droid

Every version on MTK Droid Tools on https://mtkdroidtools.com has a 
 file "files_for_delete.txt" with comments in Russian. What's the meaning of that - should't it be in English to let everyone read it? 
By the way, is this tool an Open Source and available for review? Otherwise how can one be sure that the code is safe?

Comment: If you are referring to "MTKDroid" this ["is an application created by rua1"](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2160490) (a russian user on xda-developers.com.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the meaning of that - should't it be in English to let everyone read it?

As stated by [@Robert](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/2241/robert), it was developed by rua1 who is Russian ([his/her profile](https://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=5119815) on XDA-Developers).

Using Google translate, here is an excerpt from the first few lines of the file. The comments are explanation of the lines

```
; --------- A list of files to delete from the phone ------------ 
; comments can be left after the sign; 
; the name of the file to be deleted must contain the full path and begin with the / 
; spaces in the tail and in front of the sign are allowed; 

/system/recovery-from-boot.p; This file interferes with the installation of a modified recovery !!! 
/system/media/bootaudio.mp3; sound when downloading on androids 2.2.2 and higher 
/system/media/shutaudio.mp3 

; Next, the list relevant to the B63M. On the other phones will not do harm. nothing to delete;) 

/system/app/caivs.apk; Application that sends paid sms 
/system/app/com.android.caivs.app.apk 
/system/app/PinyinIME.*
/system/app/KaiXinAccountService.apk 
/system/app/KaiXinAccountService.odex
/system/app/RenRenAccountService.apk
/system/app/RenRenAccountService.odex
/system/app/Sogou*.*
/system/app/sogou*.* 
/system/app/androidmarketu.apk 

; add-ons for B79 

/system/app/SmsReg.*; Application that sends paid sms 

/system/app/MobileLog.apk 
/system/app/ModemLog.*
```

> By the way, is this tool an Open Source and available for review? Otherwise how can one be sure that the code is safe?

From this [post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=78233025&postcount=2292):

> You cannot revive/update this tool because no source is available.
>   The original author disappear by the forum.
>   Some users developed some updates about external modules.
>   But it's the maximum that it's possible now and for the future.